# Is possible to use lua code in Unity3D

Tags: .net, lua, unity-game-engine

We need to use some specific library written in Lua in unity application.
Is there any possible way aside from complete rewriting it in C#/JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're targeting the web player, no. Web player builds run in a sandbox and cannot load external code, so with the possible exception of writing a Lua interpreter in C# (!), you're out of luck.

If you're targeting a desktop build or mobile device, then you can include [external plugins](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html) and call out to them through scripts. This means you can import Lua and tell it to run your Lua script(s).

However, this may still be more trouble than it's worth, since you'll have to load and initialize the Lua runtime yourself, and therefore you might be better off just rewriting the code.

Note that for desktop platforms, a Pro license is required. For mobile platforms (iOS/Android), you may need to jump through some hoops to actually have your Lua script files available to load into the Lua runtime.

Answer (score 2):

this is a lua solution for mono https://github.com/NLua
you can change some code let work in unity3d .I did this.

Answer (score 1):

Lua Framework might be relevant for you: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/30055

From their website:

> Lua Framework is built on the power of MoonSharp, a modern and free .NET implementation of the Lua language. As opposed to previous .NET to Lua bridges such as LuaInterface, NLua or UniLua, MoonSharp provides a very intuitive user experience with fast learning curve, fast performance, is regularly updated, supports latest Lua 5.2, and supports Unity’s Mono implementation of the .NET language out of the box, on all Unity versions and licenses, including iOS.